# Validate against several constraints with OR logic in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-validator

I have a field in a request which can either be email or phone. Now I need to validate it against two constraints - the standard email constraint and a custom phone. I know that I can pass an array of constrains link this:

```
$constraint = new Constraints\Collection([
            'name' => new Constraints\NotBlank(),
            'uid' => [new Constraints\Email(), new Constraints\Phone()],
            'pass' => new Constraints\NotBlank()
        ]);
```

But Validator applies the AND logic to the array of constraints, I need OR so that if the value fits one of them the validation succeeds. Is that possible by any standard Symfony means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Create a custom validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) and implement your own logic with existing constraint.
AFAIK that's no other way to obtain what you're asking for.

Comment: Okay, that what I was thinking of. The reason I asked is this case looked common to me and might have been implemented in the component.

Comment: @Sergey you should propose it to symfony core team :D

Answer (score 5):

There is a special constraint for that: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/AtLeastOneOf.html

Comment: Please note this was added in Symfony 5.1